# Converting quarters defined as string to datetime

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

Before pandas 2.0, the following conversions would not raise any warning:

```py
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2020-Q1', '2020-Q2']))
```

Now I get this warning:

> Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to `dateutil`. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format.

I have two questions.

- First, has the behavior changed, or am I now simply warned about it?
- Second, there seems to be [no way to define](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) a format that supports quarters in `pd.to_datetime`, and therefore no way to get rid of the warning (other than suppressing it). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is first use [`PeriodIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) and then convert to datetimes by [`PeriodIndex.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.to_timestamp.html):

```
print (pd.PeriodIndex(pd.Series(['2020-Q1', '2020-Q2']), freq='Q').to_timestamp())
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-04-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```